# Date object in Sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I have a string that is `yyyymmdd` and want to turn it into a date object in using `sparklyr` so that I can subtract one date from the other.

This code works for `yyyy-mm-dd hr:min:sec`

```
temp_table <- taxi %>%
mutate(hrs = (unix_timestamp(tpep_dropoff_datetime) - unix_timestamp(tpep_pickup_datetime))
```

What cide would I use if instead of it being a string if `yyyy-mm-dd hr:min:sec` it was a string of just `yyyymmdd`?

I tried something like this but does not work.

```
temp_table <- taxi %>%
mutate(hrs = (datetime.strptime(tpep_dropoff_datetime) - datetime.strptime(tpep_pickup_datetime))
```

Comment: You can use the DBI package to write directly SQL. Then use `spark_read_table` and obtain the Spark Data Frame

Answer (score 4):

Use `as.Date` and specify the `format`

```
as.Date("20150102", format = "%Y%m%d")  
## [1] "2015-01-02"
```

Codes that you can use in specifying the format can be found by running `?strptime`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
temp_table <- taxi %>%
mutate(hrs = (unix_timestamp(tpep_dropoff_datetime,'yyyyMMdd') - unix_timestamp(tpep_pickup_datetime,'yyyyMMdd'))
```